# What does "tuition fees" mean in a general context?

Tags: word-meaning

I read in several newspapers "school tuition fees" and "university tuition fees" but I think when it is written in a sentence, like the below one, it means "university fees".  I am not sure whether I can use "tuition fees" as a synonym of **"education fees"** or it always means **"university fees"**

BBC: [Coronavirus: Online students face full tuition fees](https://www.bbc.com/news/education-52506283)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuition fees are fees that are charged for teaching.

It can be teaching of any subject at any level - even teaching people to drive vehicles.

In the article you note, as you surmise, the fees are those that university students will have to pay for online teaching.

Comment: UK students may be charged various fees besides tuition fees, accommodation fees for example, if they choose to live in institution-provided housing, and catering fees if they eat in campus restaurants or cafeterias.